# count based on column and add as new column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, count

It should be straight forward but I cannot find the right command.
I want to add a new column (Col3) to my Numpy which counts the occurrence of a value of a column (Col2) for each row. take this example:

before:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1500 |
| 4 | 60 |
| 5 | 60 |
| 6 | 60 |

after:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 1500 | 1 |
| 4 | 60 | 3 |
| 5 | 60 | 3 |
| 6 | 60 | 3 |

any idea?

Comment: Your example looks like a `pandas` dateframe, not a `numpy` array.

Comment: Maybe it's a [structured array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). I'm not as familiar with numpy, but in pandas this would be straightforward: `df['Col3'] = df.groupby('Col2').transform('count')`

Comment: try looking at `numpy.unique` with the `return_index` and `return_counts` arguments set to True.

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy:

Create a frequency dictionary based on the values on Col2

```
from collections import Counter
freq = Counter(arr[:,1])
```

generate the values of the Col3 iterating the elements of Col2

`new_col =  np.array([freq[val] if val in freq else 0 for val in arr[:,1] ]).reshape(-1,1)`

concatenate the new column to the existing array

`new_arr = np.concatenate([arr, new_col],axis=1)`